# How to get the number of clicks on a Bit.ly or goo.gl link?

Tags: hyperlink, blogger, bit.ly, goo.gl

I am looking for a way to "catch" the total number of clicks on a Bit.ly or goo.gl link.

For example:

(numberofclick) 244 (/numberofclick) people clicked on this link

I need it to use on Blogger. There any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Bit.ly has deprecated that feature from their API.

But, still you can have a look at the documentation.
http://dev.bitly.com/deprecated.html